# Cannot access Wordpress wp-admin after changing site URL

Tags: wordpress

I've changed site URL in Wordpress admin panel -> Settings -> General from `http://example.com/new_site` to `http://example.com` and now each time when I'm trying to access wp-admin page under `http://example.com/new_site/wp-admin` or `http://example.com/wp-admin` I'm getting this error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Kohana_Request_Exception [ 0 ]: Unable to find a route to match the URI: wp-login.php ~ SYSPATH/classes/kohana/request.php [ 674 ] thrown in /system/classes/kohana/request.php on line 674

How can I bring back previous URL?

It's critical for me to have my site back.

---

### **ANSWER:**

http://educhalk.org/blog/2008/12/changed-wordpress-blog-address-in-settings-locked-out-how-to-fix/

Comment: + afte above operation remember to update permalinks in admin -> Settings

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress doesn't do that by default so I presume it has to be one of the plugins. Try to remove some of the recently installed plugins from the /wp-content/plugins/ directory. Kohana is a full php framework so the plugin has to be quite big. That's were I'd start.